# priority of implicit conversion over template constructor and assignment operator for transparent lazyness

Tags: c++, templates, lazy-evaluation

I'm willing to implement lazyness to avoid some costly computation, and delay the computation up to the point where its result is required. To do that in a transparent manner, I had this idea of wrapping the computation in the conversion operator of a lazy class : the lazy function returns the lazy class, and converting the lazy class to the result scalar type triggers the computation. This mostly works, but I have a problem when trying to use that for robust computations using interval arithmetics (`boost::numeric::interval`). In this context, the `interval<double>` type on which the computations are done defines generic template constructor and assignment operator, which leads to trouble at the compilation, because the generic template has priority over the implicit conversion, although the template cannot be compiled : its prototype is valid. Here is a minimal example featuring the problem :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//some generic costly operation that I'd like to avoid
template<typename T>
T complicated_stuff(const T& t) {
  std::cout << "computing" << std::endl ;
  return t*t ;
}

//implementing a lazy version through a convertible return type
template<typename T>
struct Lazy {
    Lazy(const T& t_in) : t(t_in) {}

    //the computation only happens when converted
    operator T() const {
      t = complicated_stuff(t) ;
      return t ;
    }
    
    mutable T t ;
} ;

//generically wrapping the lazy implementation
template<typename T>
Lazy<T> lazy_complicated_stuff(const T& t) {
  return Lazy<T>(t) ;
}

//the desired object type to run the computation on
//I can't modify CustomScalar, boost::numeric::interval in my use case
struct CustomScalar {
    CustomScalar() {}
    
    CustomScalar(const CustomScalar&) = default ;
    //this generates my construction trouble
    template<typename T>
    CustomScalar(const T& v) : val(v) {}

    CustomScalar& operator=(const CustomScalar&) = default ;
    //this generates my assignment problems
    template<typename T>
    CustomScalar& operator=(const T& t) { val = t ; return *this ; }

    //for the complicated stuff to work
    CustomScalar operator*(const CustomScalar& rhs) const { 
      return CustomScalar(val*rhs.val) ; 
    }
    
    float val ;
} ;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, CustomScalar s) {
  out << s.val ;
  return out ;
}

//some function that requires the value and therefore the computation
template<typename T>
void print(const T& t) {
  std::cout << "printing" << std::endl ;
  std::cout << t << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
  //some initial custom scalar
  CustomScalar s0(10) ;
  print(s0) ;

  //ground truth computation
  auto s1 = complicated_stuff(s0) ;
  print(s1) ;

  //lazy version computed during print
  auto s2 = lazy_complicated_stuff(s0) ;
  print(s2) ;

  //reassigning s2
  s2 = lazy_complicated_stuff(s1) ;
  print(s2) ;

  //now trying to reassign s1 with some lazy stuff

  //desired syntax, doesn't work unless no tempate operator=
  //s1 = lazy_complicated_stuff(s1) ;
  
  //clumsy, not working unless no template constructor
  //s1 = CustomScalar(lazy_complicated_stuff(s1)) ;
  
  //unsatisfactorily working
  //because both possible constructors require implicit conversion ?
  //how is the priority defined then ? The non template overload ?
  CustomScalar tmp = lazy_complicated_stuff(s1) ;
  s1 = tmp ;

  print(s1) ;
  
  return 0 ;
}
```

I'm not sure why the unsatisfactory working version in the end works, and its not satisfactory, since I can't use my lazy type generically as a drop in replacement for the original scalar type : the code using i has to be carefully crafted to workaround the assignment and construction problems.

I don't have an elegant solution to workaround this. Currently, my best option seems to be wrapping the `boost::numeric::interval` type in some custom object to SFINAE delete the generic template constructors, but I'm curious whether a more elegant solution could be found.

Comment: Can't you have a `Lazy<T>::evaluate()`? and then `s1 = lazy_complicated_stuff(s1).evaluate();`

Comment: @Jarod42 that's a good idea, but my complicated function is provided as a generic callback in a wider code base, and the idea behind the transparency is that just replacing the callback provides lazyness without modifying the wider code base.

Comment: My current hacky version is to define in my code an overload of the `operator=` of `CustomScalar`. Given the prototype of the template, I can decide to provide a `template<> CustomScalar& operator=< Lazy<CustomScalar> >(const Lazy<CustomScalar>&)` definition. But this seems hazardous.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the type of s1.  In main:

```
//...
CustomScalar s0(10) ;

//...    
auto s1 = complicated_stuff(s0) ;

// this resolves to:
CustomScalar s1 = complicated_stuff(s0) ;
```

A simple solution is to define specific overloads for complicated_stuff() and  lazy_complicated_stuff() for your CustomScalar class, as in:

```
inline CustomScalar complicated_stuff(const CustomScalar& s) 
{
    return complicated_stuff(s.val); // call the template function
}

inline CustomScalar lazy_complicated_stuff(const CustomScalar& s) 
{
    return lazy_complicated_stuff(s.val); // call the template function
}
```

Here, they return a CustomScalar, but these overloads could instead return a plain float, if so desired.

This should fix the issues with the templated constructor and assignment operator in a non-intrusive manner.

There is a sandbox to play with the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/K448jfEbv